# Adding Owners to Azure AD Group via Python sdk

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, rbac

I am trying to create create an AD Security Group and add an owner to the group . I am executing this in python.

I am able to create the group , but unable to add owners to the group. I am using a service principal to execute this.

Below is my code

```
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.graphrbac.models import GroupCreateParameters, GroupAddMemberParameters

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
 client_id="service_principal",
 secret="keyof_service_principal",
 resource="https://graph.windows.net",
 tenant = ''   
    )

 tenant_id = ""
 graphrbac_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(
 credentials,
 tenant_id
    )

 group = GroupCreateParameters(display_name="GroupName", mail_nickname="GroupMail-at-microsoft.com")
 graphrbac_client.groups.create(group)
```

But when I try to execute [add_owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-graphrbac/azure.graphrbac.operations.groupsoperations?view=azure-python#add-owner-object-id--url--additional-properties-none--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-), its throwing an error.

```
graphrbac_client.groups.add_owner(groupId, owner)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> AttributeError: 'GroupsOperations' object has no attribute 'add_owner'
>>> dir(graphrbac_client.groups)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_client', '_deserialize', '_serialize', 'add_member', 'api_version', 'config', 'create', 'delete', 'get', 'get_group_members', 'get_member_groups', 'is_member_of', 'list', 'models', 'remove_member']
```

I don't see add_owner in the dir.

Comment: could you try updating your graphrbac module to the latest version and trying again?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank You,

That did the trick,

I installed azure module which came with graphrbac of version 0.40

```
$pip freeze | grep rbac
  azure-graphrbac==0.40.0
```

Upon checking [azure-graphrbac](https://pypi.org/project/azure-graphrbac/) current version is 0.60

I had to uninstall azure-graphrbac alone and reinstall the current version using pip. That solved the issue.

Although it throwed an error that its not compatible with azure module, I don't see that as an issue for now.

```
azure 4.0.0 has requirement azure-graphrbac~=0.40.0, but you'll have azure-graphrbac 0.60.0 which is incompatible.
```